# Share a UIPicker in multiple View Controller ( Tab bar Controller tabs)

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, uipickerview

I need to include UIPicker View in multiple navigation Controllers.Can I share a single UIPickerView in multiple ViewControllers.  So if the UPPicker in one ViewControllers is updated,  then other view controllers should show the UIPicker with the updated choice.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to share the picker view itself, just the data model, data source and (maybe) the delegate. So if you pull that logic out into a separate controller that you can instantiate and pass a reference to it around your view controllers they can all use the same 'manager' to provide for each of the pickers.